# Extract Type from Anonymous Generic TypeScript Class

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to be able to determine the most elegant way to determine the type of anonymous generic classes that are generated and returned from functions.

---

Here is a snippet that contains the function which generates the anonymous classes, and one of the functions contained within.

The generics are needed in order for TypeScript to provide return type and parameter property hints when using the get function.

```js
export function createController<T, U extends { id?: number }>(cls: new () => T) {
    return class extends BaseController {
        public constructor() {
          super(cls.name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('_').toLowerCase());
        }

        public async get(params: U): Promise<T | null> {
          try {
            const { data } = params.id ? await this.http.get(`${this.base}-${params.id}`) : await this.http.get('', { params });
            return deserialize(cls, search(data, 'data'));
          } catch (err) {
            return null;
          }
        }
    };
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to actually create and store the result of this.

---

Here is an example to create a UserController.

```js
export interface UserQueryParams {
    id?: number;
    username?: string;
}

const UserController = createController<User, UserQueryParams>(User);
```

Now, UserController instances can be created by simply creating them like normal classes through `new UserController()`;

There isn't a problem when storing them directly, i.e

```js
// Correctly inferred as createController<User, UserQueryParams>.(Anonymous class)
const controller = new UserController();
```

However, say I wanted to create a class containing these controllers:

```js
class Client {
    public controller: ???

    public constructor() {
        this.controller = new UserController();
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the best way to type the property.

Using `public controller: UserController` errors, because `UserController` is a value and not a type.

Using `public controller: typeof UserController` also does not appear to work, the contructor assignment then fails because of incompatible types.

Using `public controller: typeof UserController.prototype` ALMOST works, but the type information is lost. It is inferred as `createController<any, any>.(Anonymous class)`. The two `any`'s used for the generics means that the parameter and return type information is gone.

Using

```js
const temp = new UserController();

// In the class..

public controller: typeof temp;
```

This works! However it's extremely ugly to have to create temporary instances of EVERY controller I might generate.

Is there any other way to type `controller` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that I consider elegant enough, using `InstanceType` from TypeScript 2.8

```js
import { UserController } from '@/controllers';

class Client {
    public controller: InstanceType<typeof UserController>;

    public constructor() {
        this.controller = new UserController();
    }
}
```

I can even export the type from the same file using the same name as the generated `UserController` class and TypeScript seems to be able to deduce that *both* the Type and Class are being exported.

```js
// Inside './controllers/index.ts
export const UserController = createController<User, UserQueryParams>(User);

export type UserController = InstanceType<typeof UserController>;

// ... In some other file

// TypeScript understands you are importing the Type AND the Class!
import { UserController } from './controllers';

class Client {
    public controller: UserController; // Works as type!

    public constructor() {
        this.controller = new UserController() // Works as class!
    }
}
```